# How to get last value before a colon in bash

Tags: string, bash, sed

I have a string like:

`arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789:task-definition/myservice:10`

Is there anyway I can get the last value `10`? I tried to get last character but forgot that this int value can increase and eventually becomes 2 characters.

Comment: Did you mean after the colon

Comment: `str='arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789:task-definition/myservice:10'; echo "${str: -2}"; echo "${str##*:}"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, many ways, this one works, though is not elegant :)

echo "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789:task-definition/myservice:10" | sed 's/.*://'